# Typedef and complex declaration in C

Tags: c

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085372/how-to-return-a-string-array-from-a-function) question.

What is wrong with the following code?

```
typedef char (*p)[20] ptr;
ptr myFunction () {

    char sub_str[10][20]; 
    return sub_str;

} 

int main () {

    ptr str;
    str = myFunction();

}
```

Answer (score 8):

***Syntactically:***
Change
 `typedef char (*p)[20] ptr;`
To
 `typedef char (*ptr)[20];`

To understand the syntax of typedef-declarations like this. Imagine you want to rename type T to type U. Declare a variable of type T named U and prefix the declaration with 'typedef'. That's all.

***Semantically:***
 See my and other answers to your linked question. This is still undefined behavior

Answer (score 4):

You're returning a pointer to memory that will not exist anymore when myFunction() returns.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `substr` is local to `myFunction`, and once `myFunction` exits it no longer exists, so the pointer you return will no longer be valid.

Secondly, you are not using `typedef` correctly.  The proper syntax would be

```
typedef char (*ptr)[20];
```

Syntactically,`typedef` basically acts like a storage class specifier similar to `static` or `extern` (although the semantics are different).  Basically, you figure out the declaration for an object

```
char (*ptr)[20]; // ptr is a pointer to a 20-element array of char
```

and then add the `typedef` to it:

```
typedef char (*ptr)[20];
```

Somehow `myFunction` needs to allocate memory in such a way that it isn't destroyed as soon as the function exits.  Here's one option:

```
typedef char (*ptr)[20];
ptr myFunction(size_t count)
{
  /**
   * Dynamically allocate a block of N 20-element arrays of char
   */
  ptr p = malloc(sizeof *ptr * count);
  return p;
}

int main(void)
{
  ptr str = myFunction(10);
  size_t i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
      str[i][j] = ...;
  ...
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```