# Tried returning array string as memory storing dynamically but did not work

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am new to C Programming and currently, I am writing a function that will copy the string into a string array, and returned back to its caller. I have tested the functions and everything works fine in the function. (eg: printf the string element in the function to show that it is actually stored in the array) but when i returned the string array, the output is showing nothing.

I have referred to [how to return a string array from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085372/how-to-return-a-string-array-from-a-function) but the methods here does not seems to be working for me.

This is my function called

```
#define ROWS 4
#define WORDS_COUNT 50

char **toStrArray(char str[], char **strArr) 
{
    int i, j, iTmp;
    int len; 
    char *tmp; /* Temporary string to copy each words */

    len = strlen(str);    
    tmp = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));

    j = 0; iTmp = 0;
    /* ASSERTION: Iterate through str and assign the string to strArr */
    for( i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if( str[i] == ' ' )
        {
            *(strArr + j) = tmp; /* Assign the copied words to strArr */
            /* printf("%s\n", *(strArr + j)); < for testing purposes only */ 
            iTmp = 0; /* Reset back to 0 */
            memset(tmp, 0, len * sizeof(char));
            j++; /* Move to next row */
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[iTmp] = str[i]; /* Copy the words in str to tmp */
            iTmp++;
        }
    }
    *(strArr + j) = tmp; /* Store the last words in the string because the last words is not end with ' ' 
                            but rather '\0' */
    /* printf("%s\n", *(strArr + j)); < for testing purposes only */

    /* Ensures no memory leak */
    free(tmp);
    tmp = NULL;
    return strArr;
}
```

Caller main function:
Output is just ", , , ,

```
    char str[] = "This tea is good";
    char **arg_1;
    int i;
    /* Allocation of string array of arg_1 */
    arg_1 = (char**)malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char*));

    /* ASSERTION: Iterate through the rows of string array and allocate their memory */
    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        *arg_1 = (char*)malloc(WORDS_COUNT * sizeof(char));

    arg_1 = toStrArray(str, arg_1);

    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        printf("%s, ", *(arg_1 + i));

    printf("\n");
```

Comment: please always post code someone can just download and compile. And when possible also the input data for a text and some discussion of what is happening

Comment: `*(strArr + j) = tmp;` you always set the same (temporary) string in `strArr` and "erase" its content `memset()`ing everything to 0 few lines after. also please remember that strings in c should be terminated by `\0` and check for memory leaks/problems with a tool like `valgrind`.

Comment: The erase of the string by memset will only affects the content in tmp right? As I have tested printf("%s\n", *(strArr + j)) and it shows the correct output. But the issues is that I could not get the string array back into my caller function

Comment: *The erase of the string by memset will only affects the content in tmp right?* **Every** `strArr + j` points to the **same** `tmp`. `/* Assign the copied words to strArr */` is a misleading comment. This line doesn't do that. It assigns a **pointer** — always the same pointer, `tmp`.

Comment: You also do not allocate space for the *null terminator* and do not store said terminator in your string.

Comment: Last but not least, never ever write `*(strArr + j)` and the like. C language has idiomatic array syntax, use it.  `strArr[j]` means the same thing, and is easier to read.

Comment: regarding; `char **toStrArray(char str[], char **strArr):`  That trailing `:` results in a logic error in the code and causes the compiler to output several 'error` messages when the `strArr` parameter is reference.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: the posted code does not compile! besides the `:`, it is missing the statements: `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h>`

Comment: regarding; `int len;` and `len = strlen(str);`  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t (aka `long unsigned int`) not an `int`

Comment: regarding: `memset(tmp, 0, len * sizeof(char));`  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and jsut clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: OT: regarding: `tmp = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));`  1) see my prior comment about `sizeof(char)`   2) in C, the returned type is: `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone) suggest removing that case.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "mailoc failed" );  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains the 'magic' numbers 4 and 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names. Then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Sorry about that I have edited the code there.

Comment: So sizeof(char) is 1, therefore if i were to malloc something like:
char* character;
character = (char*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char)); // sizeof(char) is suggested to be removed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding;

```
arg_1 = toStrArray(str, arg_1);
```

this is overlaying the pointer to the dynamic memory that was previously allocated via calls to `malloc()`.  This results in a unrecoverable memory leak.  Suggest:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    strcpy( argv_1[i], str );
}
```

and eliminating the function: `toStrArray()`

If your trying to separate each word of `str[]` into a separate array entry suggest:

```
char *token = strtok( str, " ");
while( token )
{
    strcpy( arg_1[i], token );
    token = strtok( NULL, " " );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the methods here does not seems to be working for me.

In that code the "string array" is declared as

```
    char sub_str[10][20]; // [1]
```

You declared the function maybe as

```
    char** toStrArray(char str[], char **strArr): // [2]
```

And these are different animals

In general you do not mix [] and ** notation. You can declare just

```
   char** toStrArray(char* str, char** strArr); // [3]
```

The returned value would be the same as `strArr`. The reason for that is the convenience of being able to use the function call in an expression. See  `fgets()` for example.

### But

- neither of the two are *array of string* in itself
- [1] is a block of 10 x 20 `char` starting at address `sub_str`

  ```
   char sub_str[10][20];
  ```

and it will be an array of strings only if each of the 10 20-byte segments are null-terminated. At first it is just a block of `char`

- [2] is a pointer to a pointer to `char`

  ```
    char** strArray;
  ```
- `*strArray` is a pointer to `char`
- `**strArray` is a `char`
- and it will never be an array of `char`. But it can be an array of pointers to `char` and it would be the most flexible use since we could then iterate over the pointers pointed by `**strArray`, writing code like `*strArray[0]`, `*srtArray[1]` and so on. An *array of strings*

> in both cases the "arrays" must be constructed carefully or you will get no array, no strings, leak memory or crash your program

### I will show an example of each case

The first case maybe somewhat off-topic but I think it makes sense in order to compare things often confused

#### building sub_str[10][20]

Here we have just an area of `10*20*sizeof(char)` bytes. There is no such thing as multidimensional arrays in C. Each 20-byte segment are just laid down one after another starting at `&sub_str`.

Since each string is `null terminated` we can have up to 10 strings up to 19 bytes each in size. Here is a C program that fills such a block

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char    sub_str[10][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
        sprintf(
            sub_str[i],
            "%16s%03d",
            "This is string ", i+1
        );

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
        printf(
            "%2d  %s len(%zd)\n",
            i, sub_str[i], strlen(sub_str[i])
        );
    return 0;
};
```

**This is the output**

```
0   This is string 001 len(19)
1   This is string 002 len(19)
2   This is string 003 len(19)
3   This is string 004 len(19)
4   This is string 005 len(19)
5   This is string 006 len(19)
6   This is string 007 len(19)
7   This is string 008 len(19)
8   This is string 009 len(19)
9   This is string 010 len(19)
```

And we have an array of strings. See the `printf()` iterating accessing the *i-th* one below

```
    printf(
    "%2d  %s len(%zd)\n",
    i, sub_str[i], strlen(sub_str[i])
);
```

Problem here is that we have little flexibility and possibly a lot of wasted memory. All sizes are fixed, static

#### Building `char** strArray;` finally

This is the most flexible and familiar way, since every C program uses at least one case. `main()` has the common prototype

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

And here we see an all-important thing missing in your program: since `srtArray` is just a pointer, you need to know to how many pointers it points to.
By itself `*strArray` is just a pointer to `char`. And only if it is allocated. By declaring `char** strArr;` you get just a pointer, and in fact it would the safe to write

```
        char** strArr = NULL;
```

**Consider this**

```
typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char**  argv;
}   stringArray;
```

And now the ends meet. In fact you could have declared

```
      void toStrArray(char* str, stringArray strArr);
```

and pack the `argc` value into the `struct` after all

**About the program:** the code just mimics what the system does for `main()`, building a list of strings from the command line parameters, even including the program name as the fist one. And then calls this function

```
    int just_like_main(int argc, char** argv)
```

that prints out the arguments.

**It does what you must do in your function.**

> Note that you must have a way to control the number of strings in your array, at all times, just like `argc` in `main()`. It is essential to have this in mind.

Here is the code

```
#define _BLOCK_ 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char** argv;
}   stringArray;

int just_like_main(int, char**);

int main(void)
{
    const int   n_parm = 16;
    const char* test_strings[16] =
    {
        "Creating", "a", "block", "of",
        "strings", ",", "just", "like",
        "the", "system", "does", "for" ,
        "main()", "for", "every", "program"
    };

    stringArray ex; // example
    int N = _BLOCK_; // 1st block
    ex.argc = 0;
    ex.argv = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * _BLOCK_);
    const char* program_name = "full path of program";
    ex.argv[ex.argc] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(program_name));
    strcpy(ex.argv[ex.argc], program_name);
    ex.argc += 1; // 1st arg. That was easy

    // loads all other strings into **argv
    for (int i = 0; i < n_parm; i += 1)
    {   // each one
        if (ex.argc >= N)
        {   // block is full
            N = N + _BLOCK_;
            char* new_block = realloc(ex.argv, (N * sizeof(char*)));
            printf("Block extended for a total of %d pointers\n", N);
            ex.argv = (char**)new_block;
        };
        ex.argv[ex.argc] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(test_strings[i]));
        strcpy(ex.argv[ex.argc], test_strings[i]);
        ex.argc += 1;
    };  // for()
    printf("\t%d strings in the block:\n", ex.argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.argc; i += 1)
    {
        printf("\t\t%d of %d: '%s'\n", 1 + i, ex.argc, ex.argv[i]);
    };

    // now trims the end of the block
    // allocated: N.
    // used: argc
    printf("\t%d pointers allocated\n", N);
    printf("\t%d arguments read\n", ex.argc);
    if (N == ex.argc)
        printf("\tNothing to free()\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\t%d pointers to free\n", N - ex.argc);
        char* new_size = realloc(ex.argv, (ex.argc * sizeof(char*)));
        printf("\tBlock size trimmed for a total of %d pointers\n", ex.argc);
        ex.argv = (char**)new_size;
    };
    printf("\tCalling just_like_main() with these args\n");
    int res = just_like_main(ex.argc, ex.argv);
    printf("\n\n\t\"main()\" returned %d\n", res);
    printf("\tNow fres the block and exit\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.argc; i += 1)
        free(ex.argv[i]);
    free(ex.argv);
    printf("\n\nGame over\n");
    return 0;
};

int just_like_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\n\tAt \"main()\": %d arguments\n\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("%8d\t'%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
};  // just_like_main()
```

**And the output**

```
Block extended for a total of 8 pointers
Block extended for a total of 12 pointers
Block extended for a total of 16 pointers
Block extended for a total of 20 pointers
        17 strings in the block:
                1 of 17: 'full path of program'
                2 of 17: 'Creating'
                3 of 17: 'a'
                4 of 17: 'block'
                5 of 17: 'of'
                6 of 17: 'strings'
                7 of 17: ','
                8 of 17: 'just'
                9 of 17: 'like'
                10 of 17: 'the'
                11 of 17: 'system'
                12 of 17: 'does'
                13 of 17: 'for'
                14 of 17: 'main()'
                15 of 17: 'for'
                16 of 17: 'every'
                17 of 17: 'program'
        20 pointers allocated
        17 arguments read
        3 pointers to free
        Block size trimmed for a total of 17 pointers
        Calling just_like_main() with these args

        At "main()": 17 arguments

       0        'full path of program'
       1        'Creating'
       2        'a'
       3        'block'
       4        'of'
       5        'strings'
       6        ','
       7        'just'
       8        'like'
       9        'the'
      10        'system'
      11        'does'
      12        'for'
      13        'main()'
      14        'for'
      15        'every'
      16        'program'


        "main()" returned 0
        Now free() the block and exit

Game over
```

**About the logic**

Memory will be allocated in blocks of size `_BLOCK_`     pointers. Anytime memory runs out a new block of the same size is allocated. At exit the complete block is trimmed to the used size and the rest is 'free()'

Ex: for 12 strings and `_BLOCK_` of 5 3 blocks will be allocated for a total of 15. At the end the last 3 pointers are freed so the function returns a block of just 12 pointers, as expected.

In practical applications we must choose this value carefully in order to not allocate very much AND not  allocate very often :)

Just for fun the first parameter will be the name of the program and a function declared

```
     int just_like_main(int argc, char** argv);
```

will be called and it just displays the full parameter block