# How does free() works in this case?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Let's say a function allocates memory for a string and returns it.
The variable, that calls that function, in which is stored its return string is an array of pointers to char already dynamically allocated.
My doubt is, when I'll free the variable's memory, is it going to free both the variable memory and the in-function string memory or does the in-function allocated memory became one with the variable one?

```
char *function() {
    //allocates memory for <string>
    return <string>
}

int main() {
    //<variable> declaration
    //<variable> allocation
    <variable> = function();
    free(<variable>);
    return 0;
}
```

For practical reasons I omitted the //function declaration part

Thanks for your attention and help!

Comment: Could you write a more complete code? There’s no array of pointers here so it’s just a simple allocate/free without issues as is.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a proper [mcve].

Comment: However, the "allocation" and the following assignment is something you need to look closer at. If you do e.g. `char *var = malloc(10); var = function();` then you leak the initial allocation.

Comment: Can you write actual code so we can see what you are talking about? `<string>` is not valid in C.

Comment: "...and the in-function string memory" - What in-function memory? You mean the function call that has long since returned? If you dynamic allocate memory, either (a) you free it in the same function, or (b) you pass ownership to some external pointer where it is freed by someone else. E,g it lives beyond the function scope. The latter is what you are *seeming* to be trying to do with this "code". Ultimately I think you're confusing the difference between a *pointer* variable and the memory said-same *points to*. The latter is what you're managing, the former is the tool used to do it.

Comment: Variables are not freed. Memory is allocated and freed. when you call `malloc`, memory is reserved for your use, and a pointer to it is returned. When you pass a pointer to `free`, the memory it points to is freed. `free(x)` frees the memory that `x` points to; it does not free `x`. There is no persistent association between a pointer and the memory it points to; you can do `void *a = malloc(100); void *b = a; void *c = a; free(c);`, and that will free the allocated memory; neither `a` nor `b` has to be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible cases:

1. Function allocates memory using dynamic memory allocation and it is 100% correct

```
char *func(void)
{
    char *x = malloc(100);
    /* some code */
    return x;
}

void foo(void)
{
    char *y = func();
    free(y);
}
```

2. Other ways of allocating memory. All invoke the undefined behavior when you try to `free` them. Additionally there is an another UB when pointer to automatic variable is used outside the scope it was defined in.

```
char w[100];

char *func(void)
{
    char x[100];
    /* some code */
    return x;
}

char *func1(void)
{
    static char x[100];
    /* some code */
    return x;
}

char *func2(void)
{
    return w;
}


void foo(void)
{
    char *y = func();
    y[0] = 'a';       //UB
    free(y);          //UB

    y = func1();
    y[0] = 'a';
    free(y);        //UB

    y = func2();
    y[0] = 'a';
    free(y);        //UB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted a complete example of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63756135/11234199

> My doubt is, when I'll free the variable's memory, is it going to free both the variable memory and the in-function string memory or does the in-function allocated memory became one with the variable one?

Please run the program provided there since it will do just this: create and destroy a block of pointers to `char`, just like `argc/argv` block that every `main()` function gets for free in C

The program I posted there shows how to build dynamically a block of strings and how to consume it, allocating memory in blocks and trimming it at the end for the exact used size

### But here I will provide a 20-line example that builds an array of pointer the same way

Your function

```
char *function() 
{
   //allocates memory for <string>
   return <string>
}
```

returns just one pointer to a `char`. You could write

```
char one_char = *function();
```

and it is just what is is. There is not string in C in fact. And if `function` is `char*` then `*function` is  `char`.

Inside the function you can `malloc()` a block and return the address in the function, with a convenient `'\0'` at the start of a 1MB block and it would be fine.

*For this thing to work we need to build it carefully*

Fact is that in general we want something like

```
typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char** argv;
}   stringArray;
```

just like the familiar `main()` prototype.

#### And why is that?

Well, we want an array of pointers to `char` due to the conveniente of iterate through hem just like an ordinary array like `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`...

But it is essential the `argc` thing. As in

```
char** argv;
```

we have no way to know how many pointers are in the area pointed by `*argv`.
we just know that

- `argv` is `char**`
- `*argv` is `char*`, a pointer to `char`
- `**argv` is a `char`, a single char

we have to build the block the way we need, or just hope that someone gently did that before we use.
If there are one hundred strings at `*argv` it is because someone allocated 100 pointers to `char` and put the address in `argv`. And after that allocated 100 strings of who knows what size, using the one  hundred pointers. And then made sure the strings are all null-terminated.

This is how it works.

The code below builds an example 10-string block, and just for fun the strings are build the way we see here:

```
we got 10 strings:

'0' [len: 1]
'01' [len: 2]
'012' [len: 3]
'0123' [len: 4]
'01234' [len: 5]
'012345' [len: 6]
'0123456' [len: 7]
'01234567' [len: 8]
'012345678' [len: 9]
'0123456789' [len: 10]

End of list
```

And back in `main()` the the full block is destroyed from inside out.

### here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char** argv;
}   stringArray;

stringArray* get_the_block(void);

int main(void)
{
    stringArray* string_array = get_the_block();
    printf("we got %d strings:\n\n", string_array->argc);

    char** array = string_array->argv; // just for readability

    for (int i = 0; i < string_array->argc; i += 1)
        printf("'%s' [len: %zd]\n", array[i], strlen(array[i]));

    printf("\nEnd of list\n");

    // free() the block
    // since string_array is also a pointer we have 3 levels

    // 1st free() the strings
    for (int i = 0; i < string_array->argc; i += 1)
        free(array[i]);

    // 2nd free() the block of pointers
    free(string_array->argv);

    // 3rd free() the control structure
    free(string_array);
    return 0;
};  // main()

stringArray* get_the_block(void)
{
    // this is an useless example
    // it builds a 10-string block and
    // return it
    const char* text = { "0123456789" };

    // building the block of strings
    // "0", "01", "012" ... "123456789"
    char** string = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        string[i] = malloc((1 + 1 + i) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(string[i], text, 1 + i);
        string[i][i + 1] = 0; // strings are null-terminated
    };

    // builds the struct to return, just like the system
    // does for main()
    stringArray* block = (stringArray*)malloc(sizeof(stringArray));
    block->argc = 10;
    block->argv = string;

    return block;
};
```

Comment: Aside: When declaring a function, better to use `void`: `stringArray* get_the_block();` --> `stringArray* get_the_block(void);`, else there is no signature info.

Comment: I use not to do this, but it makes sense. I changed the code  @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Note that is needed in the _declaration_.  Makes no difference in the _definition_.

Comment: note taken @chux-ReinstateMonica  As I told you I use not to write them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The variable, that calls that function, in which is stored its return
> string is an array of pointers to char already dynamically allocated.

It means that the returned pointer from the function can be assigned only to one element of the dynamically allocated array.

For example

```
char **s = malloc( 10 * sizeof( char * ) );

s[0] = function();
```

So you may free the memory allocated in the function and the pointer to which was assigned to the element `s[0]` like

```
free( s[0] );
```

After that you may for example reassign the pointer with an address of other dynamically allocated string.

But this call will not free the memory allocated for the whole array of pointers `s`. To free it you have to write

```
free( s );
```